# Could Voldemort have been a father by the time of the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, the-cursed-child

I read somewhere that

> Voldemort and Bellatrix Lestrange conceived a child before the Battle
>  of Hogwarts.

So was she pregnant at the time of the battle, was the child born by some kinda magical surrogacy, or had she already given birth to the child before the battle?

Comment: Because it is not shown in the movie or the book writes something about it.... Though i haven't seen or read the cursed child... I don't know how to delete the question bjt please don't vote me down... It is discouraging

Comment: Who voted me down?  Come on guys!

Comment: Not me, but perhaps the reason was that you have a spoiler in the title?

Comment: Perhaps the reason was simply what it says on the tooltip for the downvote button: "*This question does not show any research effort.*" (Also, saying "please don't vote me down" is more likely to *make* people downvote you than prevent them. It suggests that the post is probably not good and you want people not to downvote out of pity rather than because of the post's quality - which isn't how SE works.)

Comment: I didn't add any spoilers

Comment: How can i delete my question... I am extremely sorry thag I asked such a silly question please forgive me...  I want to delete the question... Please help

Comment: [You cannot delete your question, because it has (multiple) upvoted answers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Act 4, scene eleven of HPCC, Voldemort/Bellatrix's daughter claims that she was born before the Battle of Hogwarts:

> I am from the future.  The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and you [Voldemort].  **I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts.**

After this, Voldy expresses some disbelief about being a father.  But although he didn't know it, he was a father at the time of the Battle.

Comment: But she just told him, so he'd know? Or is this the Harry-Voldemort?

Comment: @Parrotmaster It's the Harry-Voldy, but I didn't put that for fear of spoilers.

Answer (score 2):

The daughter of Voldemort and Bellatrix is revealed in *The Cursed Child*.

In a scene in the play, she claims that she was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts (note that, in the interests of protecting spoilers, I've redacted the character's name):

> **[Daughter]:** I am from the future. The child of Bellatrix Lestrange and [Voldemort]. I was born in Malfoy Manor before the Battle of Hogwarts.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* Act Four, Scene 11</sup>

Although the daughter of Voldemort is necessarily an unreliable source of information, in this instance (because of time travel shenanigans), she is talking to her father and has no reason to lie.

If any kind of surrogacy was used, it is not discussed.

Comment: Great minds think alike!  I was just 6 seconds late!

Comment: Bellatrix didn't really look preggers in Hogwarts during HBP, and also wasn't preggers during Deathly Hallows whilst in Malfoy Manor, implying (unless magical surrogacy) that she'd already given birth by then, two months before the Battle of Hogwarts. Fortunately, there's a convenient 9-month timespan between when Dumbledore dies and when our heroes end up at Malfoy Manor. Most likely, Voldy and Bella "celebrated" Dumbledore's death and ended up with a child who would have been just a couple of months old when the Battle of Hogwarts took place and both her parents were killed.